# Shooting multiple bullets and changing their position with the press of a key

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a SHMUP type of game for my own amusement and I was having trouble on how I could change the "bullet spawner" position to another fixed position whenever I pressed a key, let's say I want an offensive playstyle and a defensive one, I wanted a visual difference and decided to close the bullets distance from the player, yet I do not know how, care to aid me?

Current situation:

```
class MainFire(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, filename, posx, posy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, filename)).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.speedy = - 20
        posx += self.rect.centerx
        posy += self.rect.bottom

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()

class SubFire(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, filename, posx, posy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, filename)).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.speedy = - 20
        posx += self.rect.centerx
        posy += self.rect.bottom

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()
        elif self.rect.left < -10:
            self.kill()
        elif self.rect.right > GAMEWIDTH:
            self.kill()
```

I reckon that if I fix posx and posy it would finally work, posx should add x and integer as posy with y (giving a new position to the bullet, the velocity is already established, the problem is "from where does the gun appear and not the bullet itself")

Comment: Would you want to move the entire bulletSpawner between 2 points as you press a button? Like having it teleport immediately away?  If so a counter in your bulletSpawner class to tell which of the two positions it is in, then onkeypress, if the counter is this, change position to that, if the couter is that, change position to this.  If this isn't it let me know more specifically what you are having trouble with.

Comment: First I would want to centralize the code instead of having one class per bullet as I have now, creating a fire() with all the positions be it  "offensive" or "defensive".

Second I would prefer the bullet spawner position would change with movement rather than teleporting.

I'll edit the question with more examples I've already tried

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first thing is get rid of these separate classes for different firing angles.  Once we know everything that can be different for different shots (start position, speed, image) we can make 1 class for all of them, passing these parameters into the init() function. I have called it `Bullet()` with all your Main_fire and sub_fire classes gone this should be easier to work with.

```
def fire(self):
    #this is lv2 and the base needs to be changed, it gains the subfire then another subfire set
    mfl = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, "Alessa_MF.png",-20,0)
    all_sprites.add(mfl)
    bullets.add(mfl)
    sfl = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top, "Alessa_SF.png",-15,2)
    all_sprites.add(sfl)
    bullets.add(sfl)
    mfr = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top,"Alessa_SF.png",-15,-2)
    all_sprites.add(mfr)
    bullets.add(mfr)
    sfr = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top,"Alessa_SF.png",-10,-2)
    all_sprites.add(sfr)
    bullets.add(sfr)
    #fire_sound.play()

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y,filename,vx,vy):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(img_folder, filename)).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x-25
        self.speedy = vy
        self.speedx = vx

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.vy
        self.rect.x += self.vx
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()
```

Comment: I will do that right now, I'll get back with some feedback (btw MainFire and SubFire, that's where I get the name of MF and SF, also Left and Right, l or r at the end, just a quick comment so I make myself clear, since I'm relatively new to coding and it might look confusing at times.)

Comment: I've corrected according to my variables and noticed you created vx and vy, and I was asking on guidance on how to change their position not velocity, It could have been my fault because english is not my first language, I've yet to improve

Comment: The addition of velocity here was to make sure you can create all your bullets from this one Bullet class.  If you don't save the velocities in the individual bullets, they cannot move independently from one another.  My answer will not help directly moving your bulletSpawner, it is just a step to make that easier.  To move the bulletSpawner you will need to add to the class that hosts your `fire()` function.  Changing the position of that object will change wher eyour bullets come from.

Comment: I edited the question, care to give your thoughts, I am now really close to fixing the problem